# Category Aggregate root in DDD

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

I need a **Category Aggregate root** in **DDD**. Can you show me a sample code?
my old Domain Code:

```
public class Category{

          public int Id { get; set; }
          public string Name { get; set; }
          public int ParentId{ get; set; }
}
```

***Edit:***

> I have an old project that I want to convert to DDD. I have a problem
> in the relationship between the Category table and itself.

I wrote this code. But in the **AddParentCategory**, I can not check whether this category has duplicate subcategories or not?
Is the relationship I have built right?

```
public class Category : AggregateRoot
{
    public static Result<Category> Create(Category parentCategory, string name)
    {
        var result = new Result<Category>();


        var nameResult = Name.Create(value: name);

        result.WithErrors(errors: nameResult.Errors);

        if (result.IsFailed)
        {
            return result;
        }

        var returnValue = new Category(name: nameResult.Value, parentCategory: parentCategory);

        result.WithValue(value: returnValue);

        return result;
    }

    private Category() : base()
    {
        _products = new();
    }

    private Category(Name name, Category parentCategory) : this()
    {
        Name = name;
        ParentCategory = parentCategory;
    }

    public Name Name { get; private set; }
    public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; private set; }



    public Result<Category> AddParentCategory(string categoryName)
    {
        var result = new Result<Category>();
        var hasAny = this.ParentCategory.Name.Value.ToLower() == categoryName.ToLower();

        if (hasAny)
        {
            string errorMessage = string.Format(Validations.Repetitive, DataDictionary.CityName);

            result.WithError(errorMessage: errorMessage);

            return result;
        }

        result = Category.Create(parentCategory: this, name: categoryName);

        if (result.IsFailed)
        {
            return result.ToResult();
        }

        return result.ToResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you model `Category` to be an aggregate root, pointing to another aggregate root that is its parent, it cannot do the validation you want, the aggregate is missing the data to check. 
For that you need to have all the children categories in the AR, or query for all the children of a certain category before adding it.